# How to find a link for the DocuSign app to jump into from another app

Tags: ios, hyperlink, docusignapi

We are working with the DocuSign rest API, and the signing process works well. Now we want to get a link, where can jump directly to the design app because we want to start the DocuSign app directly from another app.

I searched a little bit, but I'm was not able to find an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a URL that will take a user directly into the DocuSign Web Console, you'll want to use the Envelopes::CreateConsoleView method: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createConsole

The call is a `POST` to `/v2/accounts/{accountId}/views/console`. The body should contain a returnUrl, and if you would like to take the user directly to an envelope, the envelope ID can be included.

Answer (score 1):

**STEP 1**

To register a custom scheme, open Info.plist of the Your project and add a new key named LSApplicationQueriesSchemes. Set the type to Array and add the following items:

[image: Step 1]

**STEP 2**

add 'txtreader' schema in URL Types.

[image]

**Step 3**

Open AppDelegate.swift and insert the following code to implement the method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

     if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"txtreader"]) {

     }
}
```

> You should now be able to open your app from Safari by typing
>   txtreader:// in the address bar.

**NOTE:Your URL Schemes name must be same (I'm using 'txtreader' now) You can use any keyword in url schemas**